# Get Styles from TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE  in my project. How to retrive applied applied styles from TinyMCE object, so that i can store these styles and reapply on subsequent loads to a control.

e.g. If i have changed font, font-size, bold and italic. I want to get all the styles from tinymce and store it somewhere.

On tinyMCE change event i am trying to figure out current applied styles, but i am not getting it. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE will store the style in the `style` HTML attribute of the object you're dealing with.  Here's an example from one of my own projects:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-weight: 300;">New Release</h1>
<h2 style="text-align: center; font-weight: 400;">v1.1.0</h2>
<p><span style="font-size: 14pt;">What's new?</span></p>
```

You can grab these and do what you need/want to with them.

Comment: There are some styles which are not present in span's style attribute.
e.g Italic, bold. It is adding nodes on top of span. I just found 2, it could be more.